# angularjs bundling & minification

Tags: angularjs, bundling-and-minification

I created application using "ASP.NET Empty Web Site". I want to Bundling and Minification css & js files. How can I do using web.config?

[image: angularjs bundling & minification]

-Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You could look into something like [Webpack](https://webpack.github.io) or write your CSS styles in LESS/SCSS and your JS stuff in Typescript, so when building your files they will be automatically minified.

You'll get *.min.css & *.min.js files if set up correctly.

There are plenty if tutorials on the interwebs so I won't go into the details here.